# how can I find the directory representation of a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding

I try to find an answer to this problem related with mysql:
say a database `hello-there` then it's folder representation is: `hello@002dthere`
as mysql help says: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-mapping.html

```
All nonletter characters except underscore (_), as well as letters from alphabets
that do not have uppercase/lowercase mapping (such as Hebrew) are encoded using
hexadecimal representation using lowercase letters for hex digits a..f:

0x003F -> @003f
0xFFFF -> @ffff

The hexadecimal values correspond to character values in the ucs2 double-byte 
character set.
```

Is there a way to find my corresponding folder names issuing at mysql client something like 
    show databases;
One could argue: analyse database names and convert anything non alphanumeric to ucs2 but this is performance killer:

```
mysql> select hex('-');
+----------+
| hex('-') |
+----------+
| 2D       |
+----------+
```

Thanks...

Comment: There is no built-in MySQL command that will give you this information.  You might find that someone has written a UDF or plugin.  SkySQL posted to their blog with an article titled [Demystifying identifier mapping](http://www.skysql.com/blogs/kolbe/demystifying-identifier-mapping): it's a bit technical, but it gets into the nitty gritty of how MySQL performs this mapping and provides code (including the definition of an SQL function) that could help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's a lot helpful. The author finds no practical use with his exploration but here one: suppose you want a binary backup of the mysql files fron one database and you only know the database name what would you do? Now things are getting really tricky!